# an error i can't seem to find

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am a beginner and still learning C++ I was playing with vectors to see what will happen.whenever I start it gives me a debug error.
here is the code

```
int main()
{

    vector<int> num;
    int i = 0;
    while (i != 1000)
    {
        ++i;
        num.push_back(i);
        cout <<num[i]<<"\t"<< sqrt(num[i]) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please debug and check the size of vector on the line with cout the index is out of bounds.

Comment: Vectors are zero-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem lies in the order of operations inside `while()` loop:

```
while (i != 1000)
{
    ++i;
    num.push_back(i);
    cout <<num[i]<<"\t"<< sqrt(num[i]) << "\n";
}
```

`i` starts from 0. In each iteration, you `push_back` an element and then print it using counter `i` - **after** its incrementation. So, `num[i]` refers to a non-yet-existing element.

Change your code to:

```
while (i < 1000)
{
    num.push_back(i + 1);
    cout <<num[i]<<"\t"<< sqrt(num[i]) << "\n";
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ,You didn't just solve my problem you made me understand it.

Answer (score 1):

The index of a vector starts from zero. In your code you were always accessing 1 index ahead of what you were updating(or pushing).

Answer (score 0):

When I incremented i after the two statements it worked fine.
I dont know how but it worked fine.
Thanks everyone.

```
     int main()
 {

    vector<int> num;
    int i = 0;
    while (i != 1000)
    {
        num.push_back(i);
        cout <<num[i]<<"\t"<< sqrt(num[i]) << "\n";
        ++i;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you are using

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: I am using the #include there is no problem that visual studio can detect before debuging

Comment: The error is R6010 abort () has been called